# Showing java.lang.illegalargumentexception at LocationManager in android

Tags: android, locationmanager, illegalargumentexception

I have an application in which I am getting current location at the first page. In India Application is working fine and getting current location. When we run the application in US, application is getting crashed at the first page itself and throwing IllegalArgumentException. 
   [image: I am including the exception details here.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone doesn't have any provider enabled to detect the location, i.e it is neither connected to `GPS` nor `WI-FI`, in which case the provider is being passed as null. This is assuming that you are providing `provider` argument to `requestLocationUpdates()` function by, finding the best provider, which will return null, if it can't find any.

I would first check if any provider is enabled, before proceeding any further in to this matter. To avoid passing null as a provider, check if the provider is null before calling for location update.

```
if (provider != null) {
      requestLocationUpdates()
} else {
      // alert user asking him to enable one of the providers.
}
```

This is how you do it.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks.... do u have any sample code regarding setting the provider. If so please post it, it is helpful for me

Comment: i would see your code, before posting anything, like how are detecting the provider, and passing the provider to requestLocationUpdates()

Comment: First time I am implementing location based thing, so I am not sure with the provider...give ur email id i will  send the code

Comment: Sorry I am not able to find your emailid in your profile, only website address is there, no emailid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3690/discussion-between-aju-vidyadharan-and-yashwanth-kumar)